# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed: Must provide either labels, user_ids, or addresses as destinations.

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo un problema con un script que adquiri hace poco... pues vera mi script puede recibir pagos por partes de personas en block.io que es una plataorma de wallet en fin... bueno mi problema aplica cuando empece a probar los pagos.

todo genial respondia de la manera que queria y que tenia que esperar las confirmaciones bien cuando me toca recibir me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pues la verdad reviso tambien el error_log y esto me sale

```
    [19-Aug-2018 00:49:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed: Must provide either labels, user_ids, or addresses as destinations.' in /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/lib/block_io.php:95
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/lib/block_io.php(103): BlockIo->_request('withdraw', Array)
#1 /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/lib/block_io.php(45): BlockIo->_withdraw('withdraw', Array)
#2 /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/lib/blckdogeget.php(73): BlockIo->__call('withdraw', Array)
#3 /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/lib/blckdogeget.php(73): BlockIo->withdraw(Array)
#4 /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/index.php(21): include_once('/home/ebitpolg/...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/ebitpolg/dogebtc.cf/lib/block_io.php on line 95
```

Como ven dice que revise la linea 95 del archivo block_io.php

y esto sale en el codigo

```
    if ($json_result->status != 'success') { throw new Exception('Failed: ' . $json_result->data->error_message); }
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal.. puesto que aun estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Parece ser un error propio del funcionamiento de alguna API o framework que usas, que exige las etiquetas `user_ids` o `addresses` ... Da la impresión de que estás construyendo algo mal, sin esas etiquetas. Quizá ayude un poco hacer un `var_dump($json_result);` revisando lo que hay dentro.

Comment: Como deberia hacer el var_dump($json_result); ... me resulta que no encuentro como agregar esas etiquetas ya que soy muy nuevo... y me gusta aprender sobre la practica

Comment: Antes del `if` de la línea 95.

Comment: Esto me aparecio [https://image.ibb.co/g83QFz/1XZCSDA.png]

Comment: La información de la imagen sería de mayor ayuda si constara en el cuerpo de la pregunta **como texto, no como imagen**. Lo puedes poner [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/189865/edit) y copiando/pegando el resultado del `var_dump` que muestras en la imagen. Parece que, como sospechaba, tienes un problema con el uso de tu código, deberías revisar la documentación de esa herramienta e informarte cómo funciona. En lo que, según el nombre de la variable, debería ser un objeto JSON, estás recibiendo tres objetos en lugar de uno solo y en el último de ellos tienes error.